Fix for Error 1711 when nothing else seems to work. (An error occurred while writing installation information to disk.)
I have spent years on-and-off scouring the internet for a solution to this problem, and nothing that anyone else suggested (re-registering the installer, etc) ever seemed to work.
EDIT: Error 1711 is when windows-installer-based installers cannot install software because they complain that they cannot "write installation information to the disk". Many people suffer this error even when they have plenty of hard drive space, and many solutions offered on various websites fail to fix it. (Such as Microsoft recommending re-registering the installer through the command line.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What a cesspool this place is. Just like reddit, someone can get up on the wrong side of the bed and just scroll down burying everyone's new posts before anyone else can see them.

Turns out, it was the 65,535 empty MSIXXXX.tmp files in C:\Windows\Installer.
FFFF (65,535) is the highest four-digit number in hexidecimal, and all 65,535 possible names had been taken up by empty tmp files.
Trying to delete them with the explorer UI hangs it. del /Q MSI*.tmp handles it just fine.
EDIT: Error 1711 is when windows-installer-based installers cannot install software because they complain that they cannot "write installation information to the disk". Many people suffer this error even when they have plenty of hard drive space, and many solutions offered on various websites fail to fix it. (Such as Microsoft recommending re-registering the installer through the command line.)
In this case, the installer could not create a MSIXXXX.tmp file in C:\Windows\Installer because all of the allowed filenames had been taken, and that was the reason it concluded that it couldn't "write installation information to the disk."

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
